# Angular vs Angular CLI vs NPM (Version, Usage & Dependency)

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, npm, asp.net-core

Can anyone clear angular, angular cli & npm? I am going to start with Angular project. Unfortunately my client already have project developed in some version of Angular (+.net core). I am newbie to angular.

I am trying to configuring that project on my local machine and facing too many version conflicts error. Submitting those error (one by one) here doesn't make any sense to me. Rather, I would need more clarity/intro/relations between angular, angular cli & npm.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, Angular is Angular. Angular CLI is a command developed in Node that helps you generate the boilerplate of an Angular project, so you don't have to do the repetitive, error prone work of preparing a new project by hand. This command uses npm to download the different dependencies the generated boilerplate needs.

Angular CLI let's you start a development web server too, to assist you during the development.

This is a very high level explanation. If you are totally new to Angular + .NET Core development, I would recommend you to check [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1484229150). It helped me a lot when I was in your position.